# Automatically pull baseball statistics from web to worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, excel-2011

I would like to pull data on daily Major League Baseball statistics to an excel spreadsheet. The data will come from [this](http://dailybaseballdata.com/cgi-bin/getstats.pl?date=520) website.

I would like to pull each day of stats to it's own sheet in the excel workbook. I would also like this process to be automated, so when the stats for future days are released they will also be pulled to a new sheet.

I am running Excel 2011 on a Mac.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Have you checked ***if that site allows scraping**? Also consider using more appropriate tools than Excel. **Do not ask for code** - that is a programming job you can offer elsewhere. Instead, show your code, explain the problem, and ask for input how to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided anything for us to go on. Do you need help getting started?

I don't know if this is applicable to the mac environment, but in Windows, you can use a COM reference to get excel to automate internet explorer. IE isn't the best browser, but for most automation tasks, it works well enough, and the COM reference makes it easy. If that doesn't work for you, check out Selenium:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium-vba/

Side-note: I'm not sure what you're planning on doing with the stats, but I wouldn't want to mess with a workbook laid out that way. You might be better writing a script to get it all into a database.